# Replacing row view of NStableView on selecting a row

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, storyboard, nstableview

I have a NsTableView and I want to use two type NSTableRowView for rows of table. For selected row There is complex NStableRowView and for non selected row there will be simple NSTableRowView with two labels. 
Here is what I have tried --

```
    extension CMMAccountSettingViewController:NSTableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, rowViewForRow row: Int) -> NSTableRowView? {
        if row == accountListTableView.selectedRow{
            var storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Settings", bundle: nil)
            var accountController = storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("account") as! CMMAccountViewController
            var rowView = accountController.view as! CMMAccountView
            return rowView
        }
        else
        {
            var rowView = accountListTableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("accountSeetingsRow", owner: self) as! CMMAccountRowView
            rowView.titleLable.stringValue = listOfAccounts[row].nickname!
            rowView.captionLable.stringValue = listOfAccounts[row].accountDisplayName!
            return rowView

        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if accountListTableView.selectedRow == row{
          return 350
        }
        else{
          return 75
        }
    }

    func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        var coloumnIndexSet = NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, accountListTableView.tableColumns.count))
        accountListTableView.reloadDataForRowIndexes(accountListTableView.selectedRowIndexes, columnIndexes: coloumnIndexSet)
    }
}
```

But This approach is not working. How can I replace selected row view with animation?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So what code doesn't work? `rowViewForRow` isn't called? `row==accountListTableView.selectedRow` is never true?  I'm not sure the row height change should work, but it looks like the row *view* change should.

Comment: Yes rowViewForRow is not called. On complete reload (reloadData()) it is called. Any Idea?

Comment: I think you're getting screwed by the difficult-to-comprehend comment on `reloadDataForRowIndexes`: "For NSView-based table views, this method drops the view-cells in the table row, but not the NSTableRowView instances. "  Perhaps that means the cell views in the row, but not the row views are requested from the delegate.

Comment: I ended up using reloadData(). Still searching for more optimised way instead of complete reload.